# Update.exe not found, not a Squirrel-installed app, hosted on ISS

Tags: c#, .net, squirrel.windows

I have Created a simple WinForms app, and I am trying to implement auto-updater hosted on Microsoft's IIS
I have an issue with always returning

> Update.exe not found, not a Squirrel-installed app

I have checked the official documentation and implemented web.config file as described in [link](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/develop/docs/using/microsoft-iis.md)

In ISS I have created a virtual Directory with web.config and Releases folder that
My Winform app targets "http://localhost/Downloads/Releases/" as can be seen bellow

When I debug the application it always returns beforementioned error when hosted on IIS, works fine when it targets the path on my drive.

I think that I am messing something up on the IIS side, Does anyone have a clue or a pointer, it will be much appreciated.

### MyApp

```
Public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AddVErsionNUmber();

            CheckForUpdates().Wait();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void AddVErsionNUmber()
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            FileVersionInfo fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);

            lblVersion.Text = fileVersionInfo.FileVersion;
        }

        private async Task CheckForUpdates()
        {
            using (var manager = new UpdateManager(@"http://localhost/Downloads/Releases/"))
            {
                await manager.UpdateApp();
            }

        }
```

### My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".nupkg" mimeType="application/zip" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="." mimeType="text/plain" />
    </staticContent>
        <security>
            <access sslFlags="None" />
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

### My ISS folder structure with appropriate resources

FolderStructure

[image: FolderStructure]

BrowsingFromIss

[image: BrowsingFromIss]

Answer (score 0):

If you are Debugging  squirrel locally, you must copy paste Updater.exe one level above bin folder.